# Kivy garden-Graph absolute position of 0,0 on the graph

Tags: kivy

I'd like to find the relative position of the graph origin in order to display the correct mouse position when it's inside it. But the size and pos property of the graph class are relative to the labels too.

How can I find the absolute position of the point 0,0 on the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a member Graph._plot_area. It is a StencilView and it's position and size are equal to the plot area of the graph, meaning it ranges from the start of the xmin, ymin to xmax, ymax in pixel position.

If graph point x,y = 0,0 is in view, it should be equal to _plot_area.pos, however if 0,0 is not in view, you will have to calculate where it is expected to be using a ratio for the x and y axis, they can be calculated by:

x_ratio = (xmax - xmin) / _plot_area.width
y_ratio = (ymax - ymin) / _plot_area.height

and the point calculated by:
x = xmin + x_ratio * ( x - xmin)
y = ymin + y_ratio * ( y - ymin)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Anytime! Let me know if you need any more help. I've used garden.graph so much in my app that I've become an expert in it :)

Comment: take a look here, maybe you could hep me this time too ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816269/kivy-edit-ticks-after-changing-y-values?noredirect=1#comment40386246_25816269