# Kivy edit ticks after changing Y values

Tags: python, kivy

Which method should I call to redraw completely the graph after changing his ymin,ymax values?
I've tried with `redraw_all` because graph object is bounded to the parent widget but resizing the window doesn't affect the ticks.

Unfortunately I can't give enough code to explain my situation, but there's a pic of what happen if I set Ymax to a new value.

I've seen the method `update_ticks` but I can't get how it works

[image: graph]

Comment: Are you using the Graph widget from Garden?

Comment: yes! only the grid, the line is not the graph's one

Comment: It is supposed to update itself. I have had issues with the latest version of garden graph which was update to use a FBO instead of the canvas. This gave me issues where there was persistence of old graphics. Try calling Graph._trigger(). This is the Clock trigger that schedules a redraw at the next clock cycle. If that doesn't work, try using an older version of graph and see if that works (A commit in September might be old enough to revert to not using FBO).
There is something weird going on with the FBO. One way to fix it is to just resize the window.

Comment: yeah the resizing solve all the problem! unfortunately the _trigger() doesn't work neither...is there a way to force a window update in the meanwhile?